# Visualizing two categorical variables & filtering data with specific conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have a labor force survey and I am trying to visualize average wages by occupation and gender as follows:

```
# Compute salary by gender and jobtitle
ggplot(job_posts, aes(fill=gender_preferences, y=monthly_income, x=jobtitle)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

output:
[image]

However, given that for certain jobs I lack the wage data across both categorical variables, I would like to restrict my graph to Only compare wages where I have observations on both: 1) jobs and 2) gender_preferences.
I tried this but I receive an error, "Error in count(gender_preferences) :
object 'gender_preferences' not found"
Ideally, I would like to compare income by gender and job where data exists for both variables.

```
graph <-
job_posts %>% count(jobtitle)   %>% filter(n>1) &
  count(gender_preferences) %>%  filter(n>1)
```

Here is a data example:

```
# Print data example with specific columns
dput(job_posts[1:8,c(3,23,25)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(jobtitle = c("باريستا و كاشير", "Hotel Manager", 
"HR Officer", "school supervisor", "كاشير /خدمة عملاء", 
"Store Leader", "محاسبة رواتب", "Senior Accountant"
), gender_preferences = c("indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "female", "indifferent"
), monthly_income = c(4000, 4000, 5000, 12000, 5000, 4500, 100, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I have reviewed the guidance [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2) but can't find a similar case where we filter by conditions for two categorical variables.

Comment: `job_posts %>% group_by(jobtitle) %>% filter(n_distinct(gender_preferences) > 1) %>% ungroup()` would keep observations from jobs wherein multiple gender_preferences were noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have implemented the solution proposed by Mr. Spring as follows, and it worked perfectly:
>
> ```
> graph <- job_posts %>% 
>            group_by(jobtitle) %>% 
>            filter(n_distinct(gender_preferences) > 1) %>% 
>            ungroup()
> ```

- OP